# How can I get all substrings of a string that consist of a special char and a number after it - C#

Tags: c#

I have strings in the following format:

```
string s1 = "#1233 + #343 - #24311";
string s2 = "(#563*#534)/#2333";
```

For each string, how can I get all the substrings that are of the form #NUMBER?

For instance: `#1233`, `#343`, `#24311`

Note that the number of digits of these numbers is not fixed, and they are not necessarily separated by spaces.

Comment: `var rex = new RegEx(@"#\d+");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As GSerg kindly noted the regular expression, I just want to show the implementation:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(s1, @"#\d+");

string[] result = matches.Cast<Match>()
                         .Select(match => match.Value)
                         .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine( string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result) );
```

prints for `s1`

```
#1233
#343
#24311
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to @GSerg and to you!